# My progmatically made screenshot do not include some elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

This is a first time i am taking screenshot of screen progmatically. The problem is that when i take screenshot only my uilabels and uiimages are shown on photo. However, i also have YTPlayerView and Video Session and they are shown by their initial background color.

This is my TakeScreenshot method:

```
-(void)TakeScreenshot {
   UIWindow *userWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

   if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(userWindow.bounds.size, NO, 
    [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
   }
   else{
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(userWindow.bounds.size);
   }
   [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

   UIImage *currentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   [ResultFunction changeImageWithImagee:currentImage];   
}
```

shortly, these are my expectation and reality 
[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you show us image that how you want and how you get

Comment: @NiravKotecha please check again i have edited my question

Comment: Have you tried using `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`?

Comment: @robmayoff the same problem with it(